# Manipulating variables in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, variables

```
from math import *
from graphics import *
from time import *

def main():

    veloc = .5  #horizontal velocity (pixels per second)
    amp = 50 #sine wave amplitude (pixels)
    freq = .01  #oscillations per second

    #Set up a graphics window:
    win = GraphWin("Good Sine Waves",400,200)
    win.setCoords(0.0, -100.0, 200.0, 100.0)

   #Draw a line for the x-axis:
   p1 = Point(0,0)
   p2 = Point(200,0)
   xAxis = Line(p1,p2)
   xAxis.draw(win)

   #Draw a ball that follows a sine wave
    for time in range(1000):
       amp = amp * 2
       x = time*veloc
       y = amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi)
       #y = abs(amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi))
       ball = Circle(Point(x,y),2)
       ball.draw(win)
       sleep(0.1)  #Needed so that animation runs slowly enough to be seen

#win.getMouse()
#win.close()                
main()
```

The issue i'm having is trying to decrease the amp variable slowly over within the for loop . The amp variable is set 50. I know in order to decrease it should go like this:

```
amp = amp
amp = amp / 2
```

but every time I try these statements within the for loop it doesn't work.

Comment: why not make amp a list?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what happens? Can you show the code?

Comment: `amp = amp * 2` - is it just me, or are you doing the exact opposite of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,10):
    amp= amp/2
```

this prints

```
25.0
12.5
6.25
3.125
1.5625
0.78125
0.390625
0.1953125
0.09765625
0.048828125
>>>
```

Comment: ```*=2``` has an equally fast growth issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for time in range(1000):
   amp = amp * 2                       #this line multiplies
   x = time*veloc
   y = amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi)
   #y = abs(amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi))
   ball = Circle(Point(x,y),2)
   ball.draw(win)
   sleep(0.1)
```

to:

```
for time in range(1000):
   amp /= 2                             #this line now divides
   x = time*veloc
   y = amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi)
   #y = abs(amp*sin(freq*time*2*pi))
   ball = Circle(Point(x,y),2)
   ball.draw(win)
   sleep(0.1)
```